# soap-session with ksoap2 or alternative

Tags: android, scope, ksoap2, android-ksoap2, sessionid

i want to use a (self-written) webService on Android-based Devices.
I'm already able to connect and use it with ksoap2, but only when I'm not using the "soapsession" scope. (Simply because i can't find out, how to enable the manage-session option or at least how to get the sessionGroupId in ksoap2)

With axis and the stubs its well documented (and i already coded the client which works perfect)
Simply on android with ksoap2 i'm facing the problem with the session.

Is it possible to use soapsessions with ksoap2? (transportsession works, but i need to use soapsessions)

Are there alternatives to ksoap2? Or should i repackage all java/javax classes and use axis2 instead? (updates would be troublesome then, or am i wrong?)

EDIT:

Another Question would be: Is it possible to somehow engage the Module "addressing"?
like in axis2 : xx._getServiceClient().engageModule("addressing");

Comment: I've worked with Ksoap2 in Android and Axis2. Is a huge pain. Are you forced to work using Soap? If not, I recommend you work with REST and passing JSON between client and server.